# Spark saveAsTextFile creating directory

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have implemented the following code in java using Apache Spark.
I am running this program on AWS EMR.
I have just implemented simple program from the examples for word count in a file.
I am reading file from HDFS.

```
public class FileOperations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HDFS");
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = sparkContext.textFile("hdfs:/user/hadoop/test.txt");
        System.out.println("Program is stared");
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = textFile
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator())
                .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
                .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);



        counts.foreach(f -> System.out.println(f.toString()));

        counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:/user/hadoop/output.txt");
        System.out.println("Program finished");
    }

}
```

The issue in the above program is `counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:/user/hadoop/output.txt");` is not creating a text file , instead a directory `output.txt` is created.

What is wrong in the above code.
This is the first time I am working with Spark and EMR.

[image]

Comment: This is how it should work. You dont specify a file name, just a path. Spark will create files within that directory, one for each partition.

Comment: Thanks. Done . I found my files.Please post your answer in the answer section so that I can mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it should work. You don't specify a file name, just a path. Spark will create files within that directory. If you look at the method definition for [saveAsTextFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#saveAsTextFile(java.lang.String)) you can see that it expects a path:

`public void saveAsTextFile(String path)`

Within the path you specify it will create a `part` file for each partition in your data.

Comment: what if the path is non-existent, do I need to run mkdir to create the directory structure and then copy the data

Comment: Spark does that for you. It creates a directory by itself and writes the file in it. Just like output.txt is a directory created by spark in the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Either you `.collect()` all the data and write your own save method to a single file or you `.repartition(1)` the data which will still result in a directory, but with only one part file with the data (`part-00000`)